# How to build a secure picture voting system

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to build a page on a website where users can see a selection of pictures. It is intended that a single registered user can select 1 (and only one) picture as his favourite. Once the user does so, the score of the respective picture will increase by one. The picture with the most votes will be automatically selected as the display picture for the homepage. If the user has already voted for a picture and tries to vote for another one, his/her vote will be transferred to the new picture, reducing the score of the old picture and increasing the score of the new picture in the process. A user cannot vote for a picture which was uploaded by himself/herself.

Basically, I've achieved these functions. When the user clicks on a button on the page, it triggers an AJAX call. This AJAX sends data to a php page. This php page will process input, perform the necessary SQL queries and updates the page. All of this is done asynchronously. The code is shown below.

Here's some php code generating the buttons for every picture.

```
<?php
   echo '<br><button id="Upvote'.$picid.'" onclick="upvote('.$picid.')" 
   class="w3-btn w3-red">Remove Vote</button>';
?>
```

Here is the AJAX code. ("refresh()" is used to reload the scores of each picture asynchronously. It's not important.):

```
<script>
function upvote(photo){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           refresh();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "changescore.php?photoID="+photo+"&page="+"<?php echo $page; ?>"+"&userID="+"<?php echo $userid;?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Below is the "changescore.php" file:

```
<?php
$disablevote = 0;
$reducevoteid = 0;

$page = $_GET['page'];
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$photoID = $_GET['photoID'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "user";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT ident FROM vote".$userID." WHERE page = '".$page."'";
//this SQL gets the picid the user last voted for, if any.

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $reducevoteid = $row['ident'];
        if ($row['ident']==$photoID){
            $disablevote = 1;
            //this happens if the button pressed on the page has the same id as the one the user last voted for.
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = $page;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$conn->close();

if ($disablevote == 0){//i.e. if the pressed button corresponds to a picture which the user didn't vote for yet.
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = $page;

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT upvote, userid FROM ".$page." WHERE id=".$photoID;
    //This gets the score of the photo which the user voted for.

    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $scoreNumber = $row['upvote'];
            $userphoto = $row['userid'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    if ($userphoto!=$userID){//i.e. if the photo was not uploaded by the user trying to vote.
        $scoreNumber++;
    }
    else {
        $disablevote = 1;
    }

    if ($disablevote == 0){
        $sql = "UPDATE ".$page." SET upvote = ".$scoreNumber." WHERE id=".$photoID;//changes the score of the picture.

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        if ($reducevoteid != 0){//i.e. if the user has previously voted to another picture.
            $sql = "SELECT upvote FROM ".$page." WHERE id=".$reducevoteid;

            if ($result = $conn->query($sql)){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $scoreNumber = $row['upvote'];
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

            $scoreNumber--;

            $sql = "UPDATE ".$page." SET upvote = ".$scoreNumber." WHERE id=".$reducevoteid;

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

    if ($disablevote == 0){
        $deleterecord = 0;
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "user";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vote".$userID." WHERE page = '".$page."'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $deleterecord = 1;//this happens if the user has already voted for a picture previously.
        }

        if ($deleterecord == 1){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM vote".$userID." WHERE page = '".$page."'";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO vote".$userID." (page, ident) VALUES ('".$page."', '".$photoID."')";//inserts the new photo id to which the user voted.

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();

    }
}
else {//in this instance, the pressed button corresponds to a picture which the user did vote. This function will simply remove the vote from the picture.
    $disablevote = 0;
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = $page;

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT upvote, userid FROM ".$page." WHERE id=".$photoID;

    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $scoreNumber = $row['upvote'];
            $userphoto = $row['userid'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    if ($userphoto!=$userID){//doublechecking that a user didn't try to vote for his own uploads.
        $scoreNumber--;
    }
    else {
        $disablevote = 1;
    }

    if ($disablevote == 0){
        $sql = "UPDATE ".$page." SET upvote = ".$scoreNumber." WHERE id=".$photoID;

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

    if ($disablevote == 0){
        $deleterecord = 0;
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "user";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vote".$userID." WHERE page = '".$page."'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $deleterecord = 1;
        }

        if ($deleterecord == 1){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM vote".$userID." WHERE page = '".$page."'";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }

        $conn->close();

    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that if a user changes the parameter of the onclick function of a particular button via the console, things start to act weird.

With debugging, I've noticed that if for example, picture no. 1 (with $picid=1) has its upvote parameter changed from 1 to 3, the function upvote(photo) will receive both parameters (1 and 3) instead of one (number 3). Why does this happen? With PHP and SQL, I was able to defend my website from a user changing this variable, but I didn't think that the function will receive 2 values instead of 1.

Is there a way with PHP or with something else which can defend a website from such malicious inputs? Can this be achieved without AJAX? Because, come to think of it, a user can also change from the console the xmlhttp.open url, which can be destructive also if the hacker is wise enough to know what to enter.

Comment: It isn't possible to answer this question thoughtfully and thoroughly without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which would include the relevant pieces of your `changescore.php` file.

Comment: Are you using any type of local storage like sessions, cookies, etc?

Comment: No. Storage on MySQL only. I'll be uploading the changescore.php file shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop people from trying to screw around with the data being sent, so any validation must happen on the backend.

But specifically about your script receiving multiple IDs, each time the DOM has to render on the `onclick` handler, it saves that as an event. So when the original document is loaded, the initial `upvote(1)` is added. If you then change the parameter manually, the browser processes `onclick` again, notices it's different, and adds another event handler, but it doesn't remove the first. If you want to stop the browser from sending multiple requests, you could do this:

```
echo '<br><button id="Upvote'.$picid.'" onclick="upvote(this)" data-id="'.$picid.'"
   class="w3-btn w3-red">Remove Vote</button>';
```

```
<script>
function upvote(element){
    //...whatever...
    console.log(element.dataset.id);
}
</script>
```

Or even better, don't use `onclick` and instead set the event listener in your script using `addEventListener()`.

Comment: I'll try this solution. To be sure, does the rendering issue have to do only with the onclick handler? Does this happen with other handlers?